# jQuery UI MultiSelect are selecting all <select> in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, multi-select

I'm using the plugin jQuery UI MultiSelect http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/.

But I want just one `<select>` determinated by me to be multiple!

I alrealy have others `<select>` on my page (simple selects), like this:

```
<select name='simple_select' id='simples_select'>
   <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

And, for the multiple `<select>`:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name='multiple_select' id='multiple_select'>
   <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

When I change this function from "select" to something else, (like "div") all the divs stay "multiple". So, like this function (downloaded from the plugin site), all the `<select>` will be multiple... and I just one specific.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();
});
</script>
```

Anyone have any idea how can I make it? Thanks for reading and I'm sorry about the terrifying english (I'm brazilian). ^^

Comment: O seu inglês é optimo! (your english is great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude a select you don't want calling it's ID inside `:not()`

```
$(function(){
    $("select:not(#simples_select)").multiselect();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxWpY/)

Or just use the ID selector for the one that you want, since it has ID:

```
$(function(){
    $("#multiple_select").multiselect();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxWpY/1/)

Comment: That works great, but then my ajax refresh stop working... I dont know why. Without the $("#simple_select").multiselect() function, just with multiple="multiple", it works. But thank you for helping me!

Comment: @PaulaFleck, you wrote in the comment here `$("#simple_select").` but the ID is with a "s" -> `simples_select`. Faltava o ultimo "S".

Comment: É verdade, mas acabei nem usando esses nomes na minha real página, aqui foi só um exemplo... foi erro de digitação, desculpe ^^

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically want to apply something across a group of tags or objects it's much better practice to use IDs. To apply the code to the specific ID use the # symbol with the ID.

You can learn about CSS selectors with jQuery here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#multiple_select").multiselect();
});
</script>
```

Comment: That works great, but then my ajax refresh stop working... I dont know why. Without the $("#simple_select").multiselect() function, just with multiple="multiple", it works. But thank you for helping me!

Comment: If I had to guess, you have more than one instance of the same ID (ids should be unique). Whenever you are doing an operation on a specific, single element, you should always use the ID selector. If it does not work, there is an error somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all `<select>` use `$('select')` and if you only want to select a specific `<select>` use `$('#mySelect')`.

See [this link for more info](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Comment: That works great, but then my ajax refresh stop working... I dont know why. Without the $("#simple_select").multiselect() function, just with multiple="multiple", it works. But thank you for helping me!

Comment: Glad to help, if my answer helped you, please accept it as answered.